# Passing Python array to c++ function with SWIG and returning a vector to Python array

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am having trouble trying to formulate how to return a vector with SWIG/C++/python

I can send a list down to a vector, increment it, but want to then send it (or a subset of it back to python again so it can visualize the results of the list or sub-list

### This example works:

test.i

```
%module test
%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "std_vector.i"

namespace std {
%template(Line)  vector < int >;
    %template(Array) vector < vector < int> >;
}   

void print_array(std::vector< std::vector < int > > myarray);
```

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H__
#define TEST_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

void print_array(std::vector< std::vector < int > > myarray);

#endif /* TEST_H__ */
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

void print_array(std::vector< std::vector < int > > myarray)
{
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
            printf("[%d][%d] = [%d]\n", i, j, myarray[i][j]);
}
```

If you run the following python code you see it works

```
>>> import test
>>> a = test.Array()
>>> a = [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
>>> test.print_array(a)
[0][0] = [0]
[0][1] = [1]
[1][0] = [2]
[1][1] = [3]
```

### Attempting to modify here:

test.i

```
%module test
%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "std_vector.i"

namespace std {
%template(Line)  vector < int >;
    %template(Array) vector < vector < int> >;
}   

std::vector< std::vector < int > print_array(std::vector< std::vector < int > > myarray);
```

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H__
#define TEST_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

std::vector< std::vector < int > print_array(std::vector< std::vector < int > > myarray);

#endif /* TEST_H__ */
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

std::vector< std::vector < int > print_array(std::vector< std::vector < int > > myarray)
{
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
            printf("[%d][%d] = [%d]\n", i, j, myarray[i][j]);

    std::vector<int>   sub(&myarray[0],&myarray[2]);
    return sub;
}
```

So is this the valid way to return a vector from swig?

Comment: I think there are syntax errors in the codes you provided. The return type `std::vector< std::vector < int >` does not structure a closed `<>`.

Answer (score 1):

If the code you post really is what you are using then you have a missing ">". Complicated template classes are best typedef'd for clarity, and to avoid such typos. For example in your .h, try:

```
typedef std::vector< std::vector < int > > VecVecInt;
VecVecInt print_array(VecVecInt myarray);
```

Note that you are passing the vector to the function as value so all the vector items will be copied to the function's temporary. Since ths is a vector of vectors, this could be rather costly. Consider using `const VecVecInt&`.